# Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("PMD.DoNotCallSystemExit")

Tags: eclipse, pmd, suppress-warnings, systemexit

I need to use `System.exit(0)` in an application. Eclipse has the PMD plugin installed and complains about this line of code. Adding `@SuppressWarnings ("PMD.DoNotCallSystemExit")` remove that warning but now I get a warning that this `SuppressWarnings` is unsupported, despite the fact that it works.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Please vote for this bugfix: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392045

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To get Eclipse to not flag the `@SuppressWarnings("PMD")` annotation, look under the menu headings Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Annotations -> Unhandled Token in '@SuppressWarnings' and set it to ignore.

Right on the [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html) page.

Comment: This has the disadvantage that Eclipse does not report any unsupported token at all, and as reported here, the list is hardcoded: http://www.coderjunk.com/0JJqegPVWj/how-to-add-custom-suppresswarnings-token-in-eclipse.html

Comment: There is a bug report on Eclipse project: feel free to support this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392045