# Eclipse duplication annotation @SurpressWarnings for PMD

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, pmd

I am trying to disable several arbitrary PMD warnings for my class.

**How can I list several PMD rules to be ignored?** I was not able to find with Google.

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.OnlyOneReturn")
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.ShortVariable")
public class MyClass {
```

it gives Eclipse compile time error:

```
Duplicate annotation @SurpressWarnings
```

This is compilable but ignored

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.OnlyOneReturn, PMD.ShortVariable")
```

This

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.OnlyOneReturn", "PMD.ShortVariable")
```

result is

```
Syntax error on token ,
```

Eclipse is configured to accept PMD type:

[Unsupported @SuppressWarnings ( "PMD.DoNotCallSystemExit" )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017569/unsupported-suppresswarnings-pmd-donotcallsystemexit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to list them in an array.

Like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings({
    "PMD.OnlyOneReturn",
    "PMD.ShortVariable"  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Found just now in [Annotation Type SuppressWarnings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html).

This seems to work, note `{` and `}`, since it is `String[]`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"PMD.OnlyOneReturn", "PMD.ShortVariable"})
```